# org-cycle behaves differently for src blocks when evil-mode is enabled

Tags: org-mode, indentation, evil

I'm trying to indent my code in org src blocks, but it only works when `evil-mode` is disabled. I have set this variables for org-mode:

```
(setq org-src-preserve-indentation t
      org-src-tab-acts-natively t
      org-src-fontify-natively t)
```

Now, in a org buffer, when I have a code like this:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python
if True:

#+END_SRC
```

and press `TAB` right below the `if`, emacs idents my code properly. But, if I enable `evil-mode`, it just doesn't work, even if I call `org-cycle` manually.

Both with and without `evil-mode` `TAB` is bound to `org-cycle`. The following picture shows the binding without evil:
[image: without evil]

and with evil-mode enabled:
[image: with evil]

My Emacs is version 25.3, and I've already tried `emacs -q`, so it's probably not related to my setup. I'm aware I can use `C-c '` to edit in another window, I'd prefer to do it in the org buffer.

Comment: Please verify what actually gets called by using `F1 k` and include the output in your question.

Comment: @wasamasa I already checked. As I mentioned, it happens even if I invoke `org-cycle` manually.

Comment: We can only guess what's wrong unless you include the information what ends up being called instead. Besides, why would `org-cycle` indent? Look up what should be called by checking `F1 k TAB` in that block with Evil deactivated.

Comment: When `evil-mode` is disabled, invoking `org-cycle` manually works indents as intended. If, then, I enable `evil-mode` and invoke `org-cycle` again, it doesn't indent anymore. I already checked, and both with and without evil `TAB` points to `org-cycle`.

Comment: `M-x org-cycle` works differently when called via `M-x` than `TAB`. FWIW, with your settings I can reproduce indentation with Evil because I've customized it so that `TAB` is passed through. This is why I ask (for the third time now) to include the output of `F1 k TAB` to be included in your question. If I call `M-x org-cycle` it inserts a newline instead...

Comment: I included pictures showing the `TAB` binding with and without evil, where they both are bound to `org-cycle` as I mentioned. If you have a different behavior, I believe it's related to your setup, because I'm testing with `emacs -q`.

Comment: AFAIK `evil` is not part of emacs. Please run `M-x locate-library evil`. With clean `emacs -q` and no `package-initialize` you are using `org` that is shipping with emacs. For my emacs 25.1.50 `org-version` with `emacs -q` gives 8.2.10. That is really outdated w.r.t. the current stable `org-version` 9.1.6. You should name the version of org and evil in your question. Maybe, your site initialization files play a role here. You can also avoid the site init by `emacs -Q`. But, somehow you need a good starting point, i.e., one with current versions of org and evil that is also reproducible for us.

Comment: Was there a resolution on this? I am seeing the same problem, as I can't indent directly in the org buffer. I use Evil as well.

Comment: @SFbay007 I gave on this issue for now and started using only `org-edit-special`. I've set up some quick bindings for evil so I can come and go fast enough, though it would be great if there was an actual solution for this.

Comment: Same problem here. If evil-mode is enabled, `<tab>` stop working properly on code blocks. Any solution?